# filtering groovy Map and remove redundant keys

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy map `Map<String, List<String>>`. I need to go through each String list, remove those meet a condition (for example length > 3). If all elements removed from the list, remove the key from the map.

For example

```
{
"1" : ["1", "22,", "333", "4444"],
"2" : ["2", "2222"],
"4" : ["444444"]
}
```

becomes

```
{
"1" : ["1", "22,", "333"],
"2" : ["2"],
}
```

If there's any easy inplace method can do it.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to @ou_ryperd's answer that doesn't mutate the original map is:

```
def m = [
    "1" : ["1", "22", "333", "4444"],
    "2" : ["2", "2222"],
    "4" : ["444444"]
    ]

def newMap = m.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v.findAll { it.length() < 4 }] }
 .findAll { k, v -> v.size() > 0 }
```

Comment: I would generally prefer to do it this way too, since it is better functional programming. However, the OP did ask for an "inplace method".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
m = [
    "1" : ["1", "22,", "333", "4444"],
    "2" : ["2", "2222"],
    "4" : ["444444"]
    ]

m.each {String k, List v ->
    v.removeAll { it.length() > 3}
    if (m[k].isEmpty()) {
        m.remove(k)
    }
}

m.each { k, v -> println "${k} : ${v}"}
```